# Java App Misdraws Screen on Dedicated Video Card

Tags: graphics-card, java

I'm using a Java app called iReport, and I just added a dedicated video card, the problem is that now my Java apps are misdrawing the dialog screens.

What it should look like.
[image: Proper Draw]

What it looks like now.
[image: Failed Draw]

Is this a video card issue, an application issue, or a Java issue?

My video card stats from GPUShark.

```
GPU Shark v0.7.3
(C)2013 Geeks3D - www.geeks3d.com
----------------------------------------
Elapsed time: 00:00:20
OpenGL memory - total:2048MB, usage:467MB
  GPU 1 - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650 Ti Boost
- GPU: GK106
- Bus ID: 5
- Device  ID: 10DE-11C2
- Subvendor: EVGA (3842-3657)
- Driver version: 9.18.13.2723
- NV driver branch: r325_00-230
- OS: Windows 7 64-bit
- Bios version: 80.06.59.00.50
- GPU memory size: 2048MB
- Bus width: 192-bit
- GPU memory location: GPU dedicated
- GPU memory type: GDDR5
- GPU temp: 39.0°C (min:39.0°C - max:42.0°C)
- Fan speed: 46.0% / 1890.0 RPM
- GPU cores: 768
- TDP: 134 Watts
- True current clock speeds / VDDC:
  - Core: 718.0MHz
  - Mem: 810.0MHz
  - VDDC: 0.900V
- GTX 600+ monitoring:
  - Base clock speeds:
    - GPU core: 980.0MHz
    - Mem: 3004.0MHz
  - Boost clock speeds:
    - GPU core: 1032.0MHz
    - Mem: 3004.0MHz
  - Clock speeds offsets:
    - GPU core: 0.0MHz
    - GPU voltage: 0.050V
    - Mem: 0.0MHz
  - GPU power:
    - Current power: 18.2% TDP
    - Min power: 47.1% TDP
    - Max power: 110.0% TDP
    - Default power: 100.0% TDP
    - Power limit: 100.0% TDP
- GPU and memory usage:
  - GPU: 0.0%, max: 28.0%
  - GPU memory: 22.8%
  - GPU memory controller: 3.0%
- Limiting policies (NVIDIA):
  - no limitation
- Current active 3D applications:
---- dwm.exe (PID: 2924)
---- chrome.exe (PID: 5564)
---- chrome.exe (PID: 3688)
---- java.exe (PID: 7364)
---- furmark.exe (PID: 7504)
---- gpushark.exe (PID: 8144)
```

I'm using the Java JDK versus the usual JRE since I develop using this system, and that is what my JAVA_HOME is set to. Specifically 1.7.0 R21

The application is iReport 5.1.0.

The integrated video card is the regular Intel HD Graphics.